# How to subtract/add days from/to a date?

Tags: r, date, r-faq

I'm trying to build folders to store data pulls. I want to label the folders with the day of that data in the pull.

Ex. I pull 5 days ago data from mysql i want to name the folder the date from 5 days ago.

MySQL can easily handle date arithmetic. I'm not sure exactly how R does it. Should i just subtract the appropriate number of seconds in POSIXct and then convert to POSIXlt to name the folder MM_DD_YYYY?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Just subtract a number:

```
> as.Date("2009-10-01")
[1] "2009-10-01"
> as.Date("2009-10-01")-5
[1] "2009-09-26"
```

Since the `Date` class only has days, you can just do basic arithmetic on it.

If you want to use POSIXlt for some reason, then you can use it's slots:

```
> a <- as.POSIXlt("2009-10-04")
> names(unclass(as.POSIXlt("2009-10-04")))
[1] "sec"   "min"   "hour"  "mday"  "mon"   "year"  "wday"  "yday"  "isdst"
> a$mday <- a$mday - 6
> a
[1] "2009-09-28 EDT"
```

Comment: Or use POSIXct and subtract a day's worth of seconds.  `trunc()` and `round()` are also useful for trimming POSIXt objects.

Comment: ok that looks like the best so far. And just to be sure it handles different month day amounts and leap years correctly?

Comment: Yes, it does all of those things correctly.  You can do a quick test yourself by setting the date to be around DST (for instance) to confirm this as each approach can have different behavior.

Comment: Also, the R documentation states that $yday is only informational and cannot be used for incrementing the date.

Comment: and use `format` along with `as.Date` depending on your needs, eg `as.Date('15/02/2015', format('%d/%m/%Y'))+ 21`

Answer (score 63):

The answer probably depends on what format your date is in, but here is an example using the `Date` class:

```
dt <- as.Date("2010/02/10")
new.dt <- dt - as.difftime(2, unit="days")
```

You can even play with different units like weeks.

Comment: Valid units for as.difftime are: "secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks".

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer, since it works with POSIXct and POSIXlt fields without discarding time information while being base R. While the answer says it _probably depends on what format your date is in_ it seems to work fine with all valid date formats in base R.

Answer (score 50):

There is of course a `lubridate` solution for this:

```
library(lubridate)
date <- "2009-10-01"

ymd(date) - 5
# [1] "2009-09-26"
```

is the same as

```
ymd(date) - days(5)
# [1] "2009-09-26"
```

Other time formats could be:

```
ymd(date) - months(5)
# [1] "2009-05-01"

ymd(date) - years(5)
# [1] "2004-10-01"

ymd(date) - years(1) - months(2) - days(3)
# [1] "2008-07-29"
```

Comment: For people commonly using dates, the lubridate library is the most intuitive option.

Comment: Definitely try the %m+% (and %m-%) operator to add (substract) one month to January 31th without breaking anything.