# How to subtract years?

Tags: r, date, date-arithmetic, r-faq

I have a date in R, e.g.:

```
dt = as.Date('2010/03/17')
```

I would like to subtract 2 years from this date, without worrying about leap years and such issues, getting `as.Date('2008-03-17')`.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to convert it into POSIXlt and subtract 2 from the years slot.

```
> d <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date('2010/03/17'))
> d$year <- d$year-2
> as.Date(d)
[1] "2008-03-17"
```

See this related question: [How to subtract days in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254986/how-to-subtract-days-in-r).

Comment: rcs's answer below is preferable -- we do have `difftime` operator for it.

Comment: With difftime, I don't think you can do years, just days or weeks.

Comment: Be careful in case of Feb-29, because the resulting object will probably have wday/mon/mday slots not correct ! Try : `d=as.POSIXlt('2016-02-29',tz='GMT');d$year=d$year - 1` and check the values of `d$wday,d$mon,d$mday`

Answer (score 105):

With `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd("2010/03/17") - years(2)
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected for leap years: `ymd("2016/02/29") - years(2)` returns NA. Using `%m-% months(24)` returns `"2014-02-28"`. And to be extra sure, `%m-% months(48)` returns `"2012-02-29"`.

Comment: This *is* the expected behavior from lubridate. The documentation for lubricate explicitly states this: 

Consider a simple operation, January 31st + one month. Should the answer be:

* February 31st (which doesn’t exist)
* March 4th (31 days after January 31), or
* February 28th (assuming its not a leap year)

A basic property of arithmetic is that a + b - b = a. Only solution 1 obeys this property, but it is an invalid date... if adding or subtracting a month or a year creates an invalid date, lubridate will return an NA.

Answer (score 31):

You could use `seq`:

```
R> dt = as.Date('2010/03/17')
R> seq(dt, length=2, by="-2 years")[2]
[1] "2008-03-17"
```

Comment: there is no way to apply this to a list of dates, though, unless I'm missing a simple extension

Comment: seq.Date is also possible.   seq.Date(as.Date('2010/03/17'),length.out=2,by='-1 year')[2]

Comment: @JerryT `seq.Date` is the dispatched S3 method when using `seq`

Comment: If you don't mind, I find the choice of "2" confusing it terms of seeing this solution. For others "struggling" like me, i think the following is a lot clearer: `x <- 2`
`seq(Sys.Date(), length=2, by=paste0("-", x, " years"))[2]`. You can change x for other intervals (3, 4, etc), that's the variable - the other "2"s are "fixed... I believe it would then be easy to apply this list, as requested by @MichaelChirico

Answer (score 12):

If leap days are to be taken into account then I'd recommend using this lubridate function to subtract months, as other methods will return either March 1st or NA:

```
> library(lubridate)
> dt %m-% months(12*2)
[1] "2008-03-17"

# Try with leap day
> leapdt <- as.Date('2016/02/29')
> leapdt %m-% months(12*2)
[1] "2014-02-28"
```

Comment: Whether you get Feb. 28th or March 1st is a matter of convention. `NA` is obviously unacceptable, I agree. Thanks for adding info.

Answer (score 3):

Same answer than the one by rcs but with the possibility to operate it on a vector (to answer to MichaelChirico, I can't comment I don't have enough rep):

```
R> unlist(lapply(c("2015-12-01", "2016-12-01"), 
      function(x) { return(as.character(seq(as.Date(x), length=2, by="-1 years")[2])) }))
 [1] "2014-12-01" "2015-12-01"
```

Answer (score 2):

This way seems to do the job as well

```
dt = as.Date("2010/03/17")
dt-365*2
[1] "2008-03-17"

as.Date("2008/02/29")-365*2
## [1] "2006-03-01"
```

Comment: I'm concerned this will not provide the right date due to leap years

Answer (score 1):

```
cur_date <- str_split(as.character(Sys.Date()), pattern = "-")
cur_yr <- cur_date[[1]][1]
cur_month <- cur_date[[1]][2]
cur_day <- cur_date[[1]][3]
new_year <- as.integer(year) - 2
new_date <- paste(new_year, cur_month, cur_day, sep="-")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Base R, you can simply use the following without installing any package.

**1) Transform your character string to Date format,** specifying the input format in the second argument, so R can correctly interpret your date format.

```
dt = as.Date('2010/03/17',"%Y/%m/%d")
```

NOTE: If you look now at your enviroment tab you will see dt as variable with the following value "2010-03-17" (Year-month-date separated by "-" not by "/")

**2) specify how many years to substract**

```
years_substract=2
```

**3) Use paste() combined with format () to only keep Month and Day** and Just substract 2 year from your original date. Format() function will just keep the specific part of your date accordingly with format second argument.

```
dt_substract_2years<-
as.Date(paste(as.numeric(format(dt,"%Y"))-years_substract,format(dt,"%m"),format(dt,"%d"),sep = "-"))
```

NOTE1: We used paste() function to concatenate date components and specify separator as "-" (sep = "-")as is the R separator for dates by default.

NOTE2: We also used as.numeric() function to transform year from character to numeric

Comment: Thanks for answering. How is this essentially different than @tommmm's answer? (agree has more comments to explain what's going on, +1)