# While loop in Date sequence

Tags: r, date, while-loop, sequence

Is there any loops for the mentioned below code?

```r
library(lubridate)

Val_Date <- as.Date("2022-01-1", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
Inception_Date <- as.Date("2012-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")

a  <- data.frame(Date = seq(Inception_Date, Val_Date, by = "years"))
b  <- data.frame(Date = seq(Inception_Date + years(1), Val_Date, by = "years"))
c  <- data.frame(Date = seq(Inception_Date + years(2), Val_Date, by = "years"))
d  <- data.frame(Date = seq(Inception_Date + years(3), Val_Date, by = "years"))
e  <- data.frame(Date = seq(Inception_Date + years(4), Val_Date, by = "years"))
f  <- data.frame(Date = seq(Inception_Date + years(5), Val_Date, by = "years"))
g  <- data.frame(Date = seq(Inception_Date + years(6), Val_Date, by = "years"))
h  <- data.frame(Date = seq(Inception_Date + years(7), Val_Date, by = "years"))
i  <- data.frame(Date = seq(Inception_Date + years(8), Val_Date, by = "years"))
j  <- data.frame(Date = seq(Inception_Date + years(9), Val_Date, by = "years"))
k  <- data.frame(Date = seq(Inception_Date + years(10), Val_Date, by = "years"))

complete <- rbind(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k)
```

In `k` my `Inception_Date + year(10)` is equal to `val_Date`, so I need loop because every time my val date increases I want add a new line of code.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve. But when iterating over a set of elements (here: dates), a for() loop seems to be the more straight-forward solution: ```for(currentdate in a){print(currentdate)}```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to create once your sequence of dates, then create the sequence of index numbers using `sequence` with `from =`  and then subset the dates based on that sequence.

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2012-01-1"),as.Date("2022-01-1"), by ="years")

n <- length(dates)

dates[sequence(n:1, from = 1:n)]

# [1] "2012-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2013-01-01"
# [13] "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01"
# [25] "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01"
# [37] "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01"
# [49] "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01"
# [61] "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2022-01-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

- A ***recursive*** solution:

```r
date_seq_recur <- function(start, end) {
  if(start <= end)
    c(seq(start, end, by = "year"), date_seq_recur(start + years(1), end))
}

date_seq_recur(Inception_Date, Val_Date)
```

- `while`-loop:

```r
date_seq_while <- function(start, end) {
  date <- as.Date(numeric())
  while(start <= end) {
    date <- c(date, seq(start, end, by = "year"))
    start <- start + years(1)
  }
  return(date)
}

date_seq_while(Inception_Date, Val_Date)
```

###### Outout

```
#  [1] "2012-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01"
#  [7] "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2013-01-01"
# [13] "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01"
# [19] "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01"
# [25] "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01"
# [31] "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01"
# [37] "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01"
# [43] "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01"
# [49] "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01"
# [55] "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01"
# [61] "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2022-01-01"
```

Comment: What if i a want a one more column to be added which  repeats (length(seq(Inception_Date, Val_Date, by = "years")) times year of Inception_Date.

Comment: For example the  like this code                                                                             
Int_Yr_0 = length(seq(as.Date(Inception_Date),as.Date(Val_Date), by ="years"))
a<- data.frame(Int_Yr = seq(as.Date(Inception_Date),as.Date(Val_Date), by ="years"),
               Loss_Yr = rep(as.numeric(format(Inception_Date,'%Y'),Int_Yr_0)))                                                                                          like this has a second column loss_year

Comment: @Zohaib `dates <- seq(Inception_Date, Val_Date, by = "years")`; `rep(format(dates, '%Y'), rev(seq_along(dates)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in unique(a)) {
  print(i)
# Edit to adrees OP's comment
  x=as.Date(a[i,1])
  seq(x,length=2,by='1 year')[2]
}
```

As for storing results you can use a list and then `do.call` to make it into a dataframe.

```
mylist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(a$Date)) {
  mylist[[i]]=a[i,1]
}

do.call('rbind',mylist)
```

Another option

```
for (i in seq.Date(from = Inception_Date,to=Val_Date,by='year')) {
  print(i)
# do other stuff
}
```

Comment: That's fine, just add a call inside either of those loops to advance the date and it will do so on each iteration automatically. I just used these simple examples because you don't provide enough information for me to know exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added two line to the first loop for one option, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312964/how-to-subtract-years

Comment: Note that OP deleted their comment and updated the question, so these answers may now fall outside of the purvue of the new question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `time_seq_v()` from timeplyr which is a vectorised time sequence function that can handle lubridate periods/durations, as well as non-integer increments.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)
library(lubridate)
Val_Date <- as.Date("2022-01-1", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
Inception_Date <- as.Date("2012-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")

time_seq_v(Inception_Date + years(0:10), Val_Date, units = "years", num = 1)
#>  [1] "2012-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01"
#>  [6] "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01"
#> [11] "2022-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01"
#> [16] "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01"
#> [21] "2022-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01"
#> [26] "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01"
#> [31] "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01"
#> [36] "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01"
#> [41] "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01"
#> [46] "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01"
#> [51] "2022-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01"
#> [56] "2022-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01"
#> [61] "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01"
#> [66] "2022-01-01"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>