# Calculating days per month between interval of two dates

Tags: r, date, intervals

I have a set of events that each have a start and end date, but they take place over the scope of a number of months. I would like to create a table that shows the number of days in each month for this event.

I have the following example.

```
event_start_date <- as.Date("23/10/2012", "%d/%m/%Y")
event_end_date   <- as.Date("07/02/2013", "%d/%m/%Y")
```

I would expect to get a table out as the following:

```
Oct-12  8
Nov-12  30
Dec-12  31
Jan-13  31
Feb-13  7
```

Does anybody know about a smart and elegant way of doing this or is creating a system of loops the only viable method?

Jochem

Comment: I think you can just subtract the date see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254986/how-to-subtract-days-in-r

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not necessarily efficient because it creates a sequence of days, but it does the job:

```
> library(zoo)
> table(as.yearmon(seq(event_start_date, event_end_date, "day")))

Oct 2012 Nov 2012 Dec 2012 Jan 2013 Feb 2013 
       9       30       31       31        7
```

If your time span is so large than this method is slow, you'll have to create a sequence of firsts of the months between your two (truncated) dates, take the `diff`, and do a little extra work for the end points.

Answer (score 1):

As DjSol already pointed out in his comment, you can just subtract two dates to get the number of days:

```
event_start_date <- as.Date("23/10/2012", "%d/%m/%Y")
event_end_date   <- as.Date("07/02/2013", "%d/%m/%Y")
as.numeric(event_end_date - event_start_date)
```

Is that what you want? I have the feeling that you might have more of a problem to get the start and end date in such a format so you can easily subtract them because you mention a loop. If so, however, I guess we need more details on how your actual data looks.

Comment: Thank you DjSol and Christoph_J, I am aware of this concept, but I am in particular interested in getting the days allocated to months like in the presented table. Of course this can be done with a loop and month_end - month_start. But I am wondering whether there is a more elegant method of accomplishing that?

Comment: My bad! Now I realize what you want to do. But flodel's answer seems to be a good starting point.