# How to calculate the month interval in a dataset?

Tags: r, date, time, intervals

I have the below dataset, and I would like to calculate the month interval of for each row.(Including the start month and end month)

```
month1 <- c("Jul-96","Aug-96","Sep-96")
month2 <- c("Jul-97","Sep-97","Nov-97")

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(month1,month2))
```

I would like to results to be a dataset as below:

```
month1  month2  interval 
Jul-96  Jul-97  13
Aug-96  Sep-97  14
Sep-96  Nov-97  15
```

Thank you.

Comment: what did you try? does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287798/calculating-days-per-month-between-interval-of-two-dates?rq=1 fyi you can create `data` simply with `data.frame(month1 = c("Jul-96","Aug-96","Sep-96"), month2 = c("Jul-97","Sep-97","Nov-97"))`

Comment: I tried that, but it seems that I could not calculate it in a dataset. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do this by converting to `yearmon` `class` from `zoo` and get the difference

```
library(zoo)
12*(as.yearmon(data$month2, '%b-%y')-as.yearmon(data$month1, '%b-%y'))+1
#[1] 13 14 15
```

Or using `lapply` to loop over the columns, convert to `yearmon` class, get the difference of the corresponding values in the `list` elements with `Reduce`, take the absolute (in case it is negative) and do the arithmetic as above.

```
abs(Reduce(`-`,lapply(data, as.yearmon, format = '%b-%y')))*12 + 1
#[1] 13 14 15
```

Comment: Thank you. It helps

Answer (score 1):

It's not overly pretty, but by converting to an `as.POSIXlt` datetime object, you can then do some simple sums:

```
with(
  lapply(data, function(x) as.POSIXlt(paste0("01-", x), format="%d-%b-%y", tz="UTC") ),
  (month2$year - month1$year)*12 + month2$mon - month1$mon + 1
)
#[1] 13 14 15
```

Comment: or `with(..., ceiling(difftime(month2, month1) / 30))`