# Substract decimal years from date in r

Tags: r, date

I tried to subtract decimal years from date in order to get initial date, something like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254986/how-to-subtract-add-days-from-to-a-date) but I am using years with a decimal part, ej: 5.5 years, I need the origin date from that difference, like this:

```
library(lubridate)
ymd("2021-05-21")-years(5.5)
# 2015-11-21 desired output
```

But, this give an error because years function only accepts integers. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is because 0.5 years equals to 6 months

Comment: Be careful not to get into a clinch with leap years, leap seconds, Gregorian calendar and that sort of thing!

Comment: I edited desired result, it was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `years` and `months`

```
v1 <- 5.5
yr <- as.integer(v1)
mth <- as.integer((v1* 12) %% 12)
ymd("2021-05-21") - (years(yr) + months(mth))
#[1] "2015-11-21"
```

Comment: Edit improve last answer! awesome!

Comment: @Israel i know, the only issue I see is the decimal to convert to months i..e after extracting the 5, probably, it is `12 * 5/12` or so

Comment: yeah, you are right! I will edit question in order to explain better

Comment: I eddited @akrun . Could you edit your answer by applying what was entered in your comment?

Comment: Please revert your answer to ``` ymd("2021-05-21") - (years(as.integer(v1)) + months((v1* 12) %% 12))``` @akrun because I edited, decimal part of 5.5 refers to 0.5 years, you are right in your comments

Comment: Or just change the output of your last answer to "2015-11-21", and it is correct and more specific

Comment: @Israel sorry, I was checking your output earlier, and I thought mine is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky to calculate time differences accurately, especially perhaps years. Sources such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) talk about an average length of a Gregorian year of *g* = 365.2425 days, taking account for leap years (not yet for leap seconds, though, which are not regular). Anyway, we could assume *g* as the average length of a year, neglecting the actual number of leap days in our time difference and define a function `add_yr()` that should be reasonably valid for dates after October 15, 1582.

```
add_yr <- \(d, y) as.Date(d) + y * 365.2425
```

<sub>(prior to R4.1.* use this code: `add_yr <- function(d, y) as.Date(d) + y * 365.2425`)</sub>

This shows that we need to insert `-5.495` instead of `-5.5` to get OP's desired date (`"2015-11-21"`).

```
add_yr("2021-05-21", -5.495)
# [1] "2015-11-21"

add_yr("2021-05-21", -5.5)
# [1] "2015-11-20"
```

The gain in accuracy is almost 2 days in this case:

```
(5.5 - 5.495) * 365.2425
# [1] 1.826212
```